# How can I save my beer after long delay before bottling?

Tags: ale, kits

I have a home ale brew in a tub from a kit, and I added 20 teaspoons of sugar to the beer as instructed (the equivalent of 1 half teaspoon per bottle) but this was about 10 days ago. I haven't bottled it yet and I'm not likely to be able to for another 5 days.

I was aware that the addition of the sugar was what caused the gases to accumulate. So after so long, have I ruined the brew? Is there some way to save it?

Comment: By "tub" I really hope you mean something other than a bath tub. Prohibition is over, you realize!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the brew is not ruined. It's actually quite a small amount of sugar, and that will have been fermented out now, assuming it was sitting at room temperature (at least 15°C/59°F)

Simply add the same quantity of sugar again and bottle.

One thing that may have happened with the delay is the beer may have picked up a yeast bite if it's still sitting on the yeast. Next time, aim to bottle 2-3 weeks max after pitching the yeast, or rack it off the yeast cake to a secondary carboy if you need to hold it for longer.

Comment: Thanks mate. I guess I'll be discovering what a yeast bite is!

Comment: Yeast bite is taste of yeast in the beer, musky. It really depends upon how long it's been in the fermentor and the condition of the yeast. You may be lucky and it may not happen this time!